# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'series' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to check if rows in a certain column of my dataframe contain the minus sign " - ".

Here is my code. I get data from a csv file and split a column up into a few columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:/data.csv")
split_df = df["Maths Formula"].str.split("+", expand=True,)

if (split_df[[2]].str.contains(" - ")).any():
    print("contains minus")
```

First 3 lines run fine, but when I run

```
if (split_df[[2]].str.contains(" - ")).any():
    print("contains minus")
```

I get the error
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'series'`

However if I use a string to specify the column name of "df", it can run fine (below)

```
if (df["Maths Formula"].str.contains(" - ")).any() :
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. Is using string to specify a column different from using column index? Or perhaps df and split_df are 2 different types of dataframe? Or is there something else at work here?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean `split_df[2]` (which'll give a single column as a `Series`) instead of `split_df[[2]]` (which gives you single column `DataFrame`)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `.str` is defined for data `Series` (eg. columns), but not `DataFrame`s (tables). It requires an attribute `series` to be defined. In your case, in line 5 you slice the DataFrame with the 2nd column:

```
split_df[[2]]
```

This syntax returns a `DataFrame` with one column. Instead, you should be indexing and accessing the 2nd series:

```
split_df[2]
```

This returns a `Series`-type object, which has a `series` attribute and thus can be converted to string. This is also why `df["Maths Formula"]` works - it returns a `Series` object.